# Pause Slick Slider while playing autoplay vimeo video not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I created Slick Slide banners with iframe vimeo videos and images. I try to pause the current slider while playing the autoplay video.. I try with using "beforeChange' event for current slider pause, play only current slider video remain slider videos has to pause.. i don't understanding why not working where/what i am missing.

```js
$(function() {
    let $slideshow = $('.slick_slider');
    
    $slideshow.slick({
        initialSlide: 0,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: ImagePauses[0],
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true
    });

    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
    
    $slideshow.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){

        // pause old video (better performance)
       if(!currentSlide) {
           player.pause();
           currentSlide.pause();
       } else {
           currentSlide.play();
           player.pause();
           
       }

    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slick_slider">

  <div class="vimeo-wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/565964510?api=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&background=1&muted=1&autoplay=1&autopause=1&id=565964510" allow=autoplay  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="assets/img/img-0.jpg" class="entity-img" alt="Image"/>
  </div>

  <div class="vimeo-wrapper">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/565972134?api=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&background=1&muted=1&autoplay=1&autopause=1&id=565972134" allow=autoplay frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="assets/img/img-6.jpg" class="entity-img" alt="Image"/>
  </div>

</div>
```